# Как отключить подсветку отступов строк в VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: пример]

Подсветка отступов появилась после обновления VS Code. Никак не могу ее убрать.

Comment: как и поставили. по умолчанию эта функция отключена

Comment: возможно, у вас установлено расширение `indent-rainbow`, которое добавляет подобный функционал. отключите или удалите его, если этот эффект вам не по вкусу

Comment: Если точнее, то эта функция не отключена по умолчанию, её вообще нет.